# Facebook Ads Insights: How to get data aggregated by Sun - Sat week, instead of Mon - Sun week?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

In ads insights api, when I try to call an end point with time_increment set to 7, it groups the data by week.

However the week that it uses is a Monday-Sunday week. How can I get the data grouped by a Sunday - Saturday week?

An additional info is that we are a reporting solution provider , and we fetch data for different clients that are spread across the globe. Some clients want the data grouped by Monday-Sunday week, where as some want the data to be grouped by Sunday - Saturday week. So I was wondering is this something that is configurable.

Comment: I doubt this API cares about weeks. Try setting TimeRanges in such way that first days is Sunday and see if that helps. Or you can outright give it pre-formed `time_ranges` yourself, where you build it exactly the way you want. More [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/)

Comment: @M.Prokhorov The first option(Try setting TimeRanges in such way that first days is Sunday and see if that helps.)  itself worked. I think the second also will work.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: Ok, I'll make it an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semantics of that API parameters imply that Facebook API itself doesn't force any notion of a week.

So you need to set TimeRange parameter in your request in such way that first day of your parameter is Sunday:

```
request: {
    time_range: {
        since: getClosestSundayInThePast(startDate),
        until: getClosestSundayInTheFuture(endDate).minus(1, 'day')
    },
    time_increment: 7
}
```

Implementation of `getClosestSunday(Date)` I'll leave to you, it shouldn't be hard.

Alternatively, you can prebuild an array of TimeRange objects (with syntax similar to above):

```
var date = startDate;
var ranges = [date];
do {
  date = date.plus(7, 'day');
  ranges.push(date)
} while (date < endDate);

request: {
    time_ranges: ranges
}
```

For more details (such as date formats, etc.), see also an [API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/).